# What are the differences between OpenFOAM 10 and OpenFOAM® v2212?

Tags: openfoam

While **OpenFOAM 10** (release date July 2022) is located on [OpenFOAM.org](http://openfoam.org/release/10/) and [GitHub](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-10),
**OpenFOAM® v2212** (published December 2022) is from [OpenFOAM.com](https://www.openfoam.com/news/main-news/openfoam-v2212/) and on [GitLab](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/tree/OpenFOAM-v2212).
Both versions sharing an unofficial Wikipedia representation on [Unofficial OpenFOAM wiki](https://openfoamwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page).

Is there a difference on results from each versions implemented solvers running and if so, what are tasks for providing compatibility between these newest release versions (also considering source included tutorials)?

Answer (score 3):

This is an age old question (openfoam.org vs openfoam.com). The direct answer can be found in the links below.

https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/197150-openfoam-com-versus-openfoam-org-version-use.html

https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenFOAM/comments/o6spq5/openfoamorg_versus_openfoamcom/

Basically, both are two forks of the same software, with some code added or removed. Community contribution is higher in OpenFOAM.org's version and some advanced solvers are added in OpenFOAM.com's version.

They are very similar in most aspects and differ only in very advanced solvers / simulations. By the time people start to understand those differences, they can choose the version for themselves.

Also, note that ESI-OpenFOAM can and will contain code from OpenFOAM.org, but not the other way around. The code added in ESI-OpenFOAM stays only there. It is one of the reasons it is used more in industries.

For basic usage or learning, both versions are nearly equal. I generally stick with the OpenFOAM.org's version as it is used in more academia (from personal experiences) and it is more accessible (the documentation and tutorials) (personal opinion).

To find what exact code differs for both versions, we have to see the commit history and examine solvers manually. I'll keep on adding to this answer as I find more stuff (asking friends and professors).

Comment: Thx, @berinaniesh, above links information is mostly about law, organizational and authors related details, but few explanation about compatibility between these versions solvers/methods and/or how to transfer tutorial cases between these versions. Maybe things changed for newest releases?

Comment: If you are unsure, I would personally recommend to stick with openfoam.org's version.

Comment: please use Blockquote when you are copying from another source

Comment: Most of the answer is what I know from my professor, classmates and many sources on the internet. Nothing is directly copied from anywhere @AhmedSbai